# How to partition a users table

Tags: postgresql

What would be the best strategy for partitioning a 'users' table that looks like this:

```
create table users
(
    id         uuid default gen_random_uuid() primary key,
    username   varchar not null unique,
    password   varchar not null,
    email      varchar not null unique,
    created_at timestamp with time zone default now(),
    updated_at timestamp with time zone default now()
)
```

The requirements for the table are:

- support UPDATE of username, password, email, updated_at; and DELETE of records.
- foreign keys referencing it, including the ones with `on delete cascade` clause.
- the table has unique constraints.

NOTE: the last 2 requirements can be omitted, by implementing the logic in the application level.

The objective is to make the standard authentication flow queries faster.

Comment: I suppose you also want to support `INSERT` statements? :-)

Comment: What exactly is slow about the current "*standard authentication flow queries*"? Please post them and their execution plans. Why do you think partitioning will help?

Comment: A table storing user account is usually not a candidate for partitioning. Why do you think you need it? Do you expect hundreds of million of users? Do you need to delete "old" ones on a regular basis? The "standard authentication flow" is most likely using queries with a condition on `username` and `password` and for that partitioning won't really speed up things (it will probably make things slower).

Comment: @Bergi i was writing about the possibility to update in the context of the partition key, as some key choices will restrict record updates.. This is one of the limitations of partitioning. Insert is never a problem in this regard.